# SQL date insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have run a query to get certain results that i am happy with but I now wnat to insert a piece of code which will force a user to manually input a date range for the results.

My code so far is .....

```
SELECT     vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID.PACOSTCATID AS COST_CAT_CODE, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID.PACOSTCATNME AS COST_CAT_NAME, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.COST, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.ITEMDESC AS ITEM, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.CREDITOR, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.DOC_NUM AS DOCUMENT_NUMBER, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.DESCRIPTION, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.DOC_DATE AS DATE,  
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.PROJECT AS JOB_CODE_STAGE, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.COMPOUNDNAME AS CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION


FROM         vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID INNER JOIN
                      vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt ON vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID.PACOSTCATID = vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.PACOSTCATID


SELECT  CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, CAST(SUM(COST) AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS TOTAL_COST 

FROM    (   
        SELECT COMPOUNDNAME AS CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, COST  
        FROM   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt  
        ) A 
GROUP BY  
        CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION
```

and I was thinking along the lines of inserting a string of code like ....

```
SELECT * FROM vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt
WHERE (DOC_DATE >= @DateFrom) 
AND (DOC_DATE  <= @DateTo)
```

But I am getting stuck on how to get this to work.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

All work is being done on SQL Server Management Studio 2005 and will be deployed on MS Visual Studio eventually.

SORRY I missed this off when pasting my code.  I declared my varibles like this ...

```
DECLARE @DateFrom datetime 
DECLARE @DateTo datetime
```

then the following.....

```
SELECT * FROM vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt 
WHERE (DOC_DATE >= @DateFrom)  
AND (DOC_DATE  <= @DateTo)
```

All it did was return a blank results pane?

Comment: So what have you tried, and why are you stuck? Which aspect of it is causing you problems?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: you should consider using table aliases in your queries, it will make them much easier to read.

Comment: I have tried the date referenced coding mentioned but this returned an error and as this is above what I normally do with sql I am hoping someone can show me the way forwards with how best to achieve this?

Comment: when you say it is not working, are you getting an error message? Where are you declaring the @DateTo and @DateFrom?

Comment: Curious as to @bluefeet's question as well, but also wanted to add, unless you don't care about missing data on the last day in your range, or you can guarantee that no date will ever have a non-midnight time component, it should be `>= @DateFrom AND < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateTo);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not provided a ton of details about your issue, I am going to try to take a shot at it.

If you want to pass in some sort of parameter (dates) to your query, then you will want to use a stored procedure.  Something similar to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
(
    @DateFrom   datetime,
    @DateTo     datetime
)
AS

SELECT * 
FROM vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt
WHERE DOC_DATE >= @DateFrom 
    AND DOC_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateTo)
```

This will allow you to pass in the DateTo and the DateFrom to the query.  Then if you want to use a WHERE clause in your second query that you posted, you would do the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
(
    @DateFrom   datetime,
    @DateTo     datetime
)
AS

SELECT  CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, CAST(SUM(COST) AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS TOTAL_COST 
FROM   
(   
    SELECT COMPOUNDNAME AS CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, COST  
    FROM   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt  
    WHERE DOC_DATE >= @DateFrom 
        AND DOC_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateTo)
) A 
GROUP BY CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION
```

Then when you go to query the results, you would execute the following:

```
exec dbo.test '5/1/12', '5/30/12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon declaration, the variables are initalized to `NULL`.

This condition:

```
WHERE (DOC_DATE >= @DateFrom)  
AND (DOC_DATE  <= @DateTo)
```

won't hold for any record with the variables set to `NULL`.

Assign some values to your variables.